# how to get the page title to switch names by the jquery UI tabs selected in the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery UI tabs in an html 5 page, #tabs-1, #tabs-2, etc...and it was suggested to see if I could get the page title to change when switching each tab. If you can supply the complete code, that would be helpful and I am not a javascript coder.

Comment: have not tried anything, still looking for code to try

Answer (score 0):

Setting `document.title` will work.

```
document.title = "Whatever You Want";
```

Comment: What goes around this document.title = "Whatever You Want";

Comment: You would put it in a javascript function that is called when you change tabs, such as an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can chang the title when 'change' is triggered from your tabs element

```
$(tabsElement).change(function () {
 document.title = "change according to selected tab";
})
```

Comment: do I use the id="tabs" [#tabs] in place of "change according to selected tab"? And does this go into the body or head

Comment: There are multiple tabs